# How to disable local file access for web browsers?

Tags: debian, iceweasel

When I type in a web browser, for example iceweasel, a local path on Debian I have access to local files. Is there any way to disable this option for all web browsers?

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  What local path and action are you referring to?  Most browsers have the ability to display a locally stored file if you enter it in the URL box or browse to it from a menu.  Are you saying you want to limit the browser to displaying only online web pages?

Comment: Yes exactly i want to achieve it